# Resultset To List

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I want to convert my Resultset to List in my JSP page. and want to display all the values.  This is my query:

```
SELECT userId, userName 
  FROM user;
```

I have executed that using **preparedstatement** and got the **Resultset**. But how to convert it as a **List** and  want to display the result like this:

```
userID  userName
------------------
1001    user-X 
1006    user-Y  
1007    user-Z
```

Comment: Is there an instance of ResultSet available in the JSP (e.g. created within scriptlet tags) or is this being created in a servlet, and passed into the JSP?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to iterate over the *ResultSet* object in a loop, row by row, to pull out each column value:

```
List ll = new LinkedList();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT userid, username FROM USER");

// Fetch each row from the result set
while (rs.next()) {
  int i = rs.getInt("userid");
  String str = rs.getString("username");

  //Assuming you have a user object
  User user = new User(i, str);

  ll.add(user);
}
```

Comment: only thing that could be fixed is to change the statement to prepared statement (as the OP)

Comment: True, but it doesn't really matter because the question only regards getting data out of the ResultSet object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and discussions on this. I got it. I added those resultset in the List and Iterate it.

Answer (score 10):

You could always use [Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) and the [MapListHandler](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/handlers/MapListHandler.html). From the doc:

> ResultSetHandler implementation that
>   converts a ResultSet into a List of
>   Maps

so it'll take a lot of boilerplate code out of your hands.

Answer (score 8):

A ResultSet should never get as far as a JSP.  It should be mapping into a data structure or object and closed inside the method scope in which it was created.  It's a database cursor, a scarce resource.  Your app will run out of them soon if you persist with such a design.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, Object> resMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                resMap.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
            }
            result.add(resMap);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of lists.

```
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
   int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

   List row = null;
   List table = new List();

   while(rs.next())
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          row.add(rs.next(i);

       tabla.add(row)
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).