# java.sql.SQLException: There is no column named:

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am using Netbeans IDE to develop a desktop Java App.  I have an embedded Derby database which has a few tables.  All of the tables are in the APP schema.  The problem I am having is that a query I am making to the DB is coming back with the above exception.  I know the table exists and if I run the exact same SQL query from inside the editor it functions as expected.  I am looking for help with the problem but more so looking for help as to how you would troubleshoot a problem like this.  I have attached some code and the stack trace.  Please don't hesitate to ask for more info if it will help

```
        public static void doKeywordListDisplayLogic() {

    try {
        SimpleQuery keywordIdQuery = new SimpleQuery();
        keywordIdQuery.setSelectExpressionList("*");
        keywordIdQuery.setDataSource("KEYWORD_LOOKUP");
        keywordIdQuery.setWherePredicates("SDS_NUMBER");
        keywordIdQuery.setComparisonOperator("=");
        keywordIdQuery.setQueryPredicate(selectedSdsNumber);//selectedSdsNumber comes from a previous query and table row selection.
        keywordIdQuery.simpleQuery();

        String keyId = rs.getString("KEY_ID");
        System.out.println(keyId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
    public void simpleQuery() {

    try {
        conn = DbCommunication.JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
        String dbQuery = "SELECT ".concat(selectExpressionList).concat(" FROM ").concat(dataSource).concat(" WHERE ").concat(wherePredicates).concat(" ").concat(comparisonOperator).concat(" ").concat(queryPredicate);
        System.out.println(dbQuery);

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(dbQuery);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

---

```
***THE SELECT SQL QUERY BELOW IS THE FINAL STRING SUBMITTED TO THE DB***

SELECT * FROM LOCATION_LOOKUP WHERE SDS_NUMBER = 998

java.sql.SQLException: There is no column named: KEY_ID.  
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at RecordHandling.PopulateRecord.doKeywordListDisplayLogic(PopulateRecord.java:264)
at RecordHandling.PopulateRecord.doRowRetrieval(PopulateRecord.java:202)
at Gui.mainFrame.jButton7ActionPerformed(mainFrame.java:717)
at Gui.mainFrame.access$400(mainFrame.java:25)
at Gui.mainFrame$5.actionPerformed(mainFrame.java:232)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: There is no column named: KEY_ID.  
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.findColumnX(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.findColumnX(Unknown Source)
... 42 more
```

Comment: What is the definition of the table?

Comment: MichaelT thanks for the reply.  What do you mean by definition of the table?

Comment: can you print dbquery string? and also table schema

Comment: the dbquery string is printed just above the stacktrace.  That exact string works in the editor but not in the application.  Is there a way to print the table schema or should I just describe it?

Comment: It's telling you your table has no column named "KEY_ID". I suspect it's correct.

Comment: Brian. I understand what the exception is telling me but not why.  The same exact query returns accurate results when used from within the Netbeans Services window. It would be helpful if you could lend some advice on why there is a difference between the two requests of the same query.

Comment: who ever gave me the downgrade, could you please explain why so I can fix the issue in further posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`There is no column named: KEY_ID`

Instead of retrieving using column name,

```
    String keyId = rs.getString("KEY_ID");
```

try retrieve using index:

```
    String keyId = rs.getString(indexOfKeyId);//if key_id is at column 2 in table, then  rs.getString(2)
```

To troubleshoot, display all value from `rs`, and see if your desired output(key id) is there.

Comment: index causes a compiler error.  Does something need to imported or is that something I need to implement?  Sorry for my ignorance.  I am new to sql and java but I am learning and I greatly appreciate everyones quick responses.

Comment: how did you write it?

Comment: I did not fully understand this until you added the comment.  That works perfectly!  Now what is the reason that it fails when you use the column name?

Comment: perhaps `KEY_ID` is not read as `KEY_ID` , and it depends on IDE. I believe in some IDE it will work

Comment: That's odd.  At least you have given me a work around.  Much appreciated.  If you don't mind could you give me an example of how I can make that query then loop through the result set and print all of the multiple results?

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1966870/2817802) and for more info you may read the [ResultSet Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)