# Cannot create ArrayList with ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, resultset

I'm trying to create an ArrayList based on the ResultSet. Using the while loop to iterate through all the rows I can get only the first row (With rs.next() and rs.first()) as well as the last one (rs.last()).

```
public ArrayList retrieveFromDb(Statement myStmt){    

    try{
        ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product";
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("barcode"));
            inner.add(rs.getString("barcode"));
            System.out.println("done");

        return inner;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Product.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I need is for the ArrayList to get the information from all the rows.

**UPDATE:** It looks like I failed to properly return the list by returning it too early (as pointed out in the answer below.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resultset To List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966836/resultset-to-list)

Comment: You have placed the return inner statement inside the while loop. Place the return statement outside the while loop and try.

Comment: Hello @FranciscoMateo, thank you for taking the time to read my question. Unfortunately the possible duplicate didn't help me out. If I missed something please let me know.

Comment: *the possible duplicate didn't help me out.* then explain why that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning your list too early. Move your `return` statement to the end.

Reread the Oracle Tutorial, [*Retrieving and Modifying Values from Result Sets*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html).

Also, [close your result set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) when finished using it.

We can make your returned list a more general `List` rather than `ArrayList`, and more specifically of type `String`.

```
public List< String > retrieveFromDb( Statement myStmt ){    
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>() ;

    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product ;" ;
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery( query ) ;

        while( rs.next() ){  // Looping the rows of the result set: first row, second row, third, fourth, and so on.
            String barcode = rs.getString( "barcode" ) ;
            list.add( rs.getString( "barcode" ) );
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Product.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if( Objects.nonNull( rs ) ) {
            rs.close() ;  // <--- Best to close your result set when done.
        }
    }

    return list ;
}
```

Even better, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close your result set.

```
public List< String > retrieveFromDb( Statement myStmt ){    
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>() ;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM product ;" ;

    try (
        ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery( query ) ;
    )
    {
        while( rs.next() ){  // Looping the rows of the result set: first row, second row, third, fourth, and so on.
            String barcode = rs.getString( "barcode" ) ;
            list.add( rs.getString( "barcode" ) );
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Product.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return list ;
}
```

Tip: I recommend always terminating your SQL statements properly, with a semicolon. You may get away without it, but making it a habit can prevent problems in the long run.