# Spring Boot rest controller: how to return clean json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I've set this method to return a response from a Spring Boot rest controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> get(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.ReportDAO.read("dbuser1"), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

And this is the DAO method:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public Map<String, Object> read(String testParam) {
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = Arrays.asList(new SqlParameter(Types.NVARCHAR));
    CallableStatementCreator csc = new CallableStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call test (?)}");
            cs.setString(1, testParam);
            return cs;
        }
    };

    return jdbcTemplate.call(csc, parameters);
}
```

I'm successfully having a json object as response but in this format:

```
#result-set-1: [ {…}, {…} ]
```

while I'm expecting to have:

```
[ {…}, {…} ]
```

Why is the resultset inserted into `#result-set-1` key? How can I modify this behaviour?

Comment: That is probably what your dao returns.

Comment: @M.Deinum my bad, I've updated the question with the DAO code

Comment: As @M.Deinum said, your dao is returning an object that serializes that way. Inspect the object to extract the result set before returning it from your endpoint. 

The documentation for JdbcTemplate#call says “ Extract returned ResultSets from the completed stored procedure.”  

So it looks like what you want to do is take the values combined into one list: ReportDao.read(“blah”).values().flatMap(l -> ((Collection) l).stream().collect(toList()). 

You’ll need to check what kind of object is actually in that map before casting to a Collection. I’m guessing it returns a ResultSet.

Comment: You’ll have to modify the collect operation I wrote to fit whatever type the jdbcTemplate.call actually returns for Map values

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen an example?

Comment: @Mark I posted an answer below with a <hopefully> clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`JdbcTemplate#call` returns Map<String, Object> You can alter this behaviour by specifically extracting key from map using key `#result-set-1`.

This is how i have done it:

sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sample_log` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Insert statements:

```sql
insert into sample_log (message) values('West Country');
insert into sample_log (message) values('Welcome User');
```

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE  `fetch_sample_logs`(
    in message_query  varchar(30)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM new_db.sample_log where message like message_query;
END
```

Controller

```java
@RequestMapping("/logs")
@RestController
class SampleLogController {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    SampleLogController(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @GetMapping("/call")
    public Object get() {
        final Map<String, Object> call = jdbcTemplate.call(connection -> {
            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call fetch_sample_logs (?)}");
            cs.setString(1, "%wel%");
            return cs;
        }, Collections.singletonList(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR)));
        return Optional.of(call.getOrDefault("#result-set-1", Collections.emptyList()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting that you extract all the result-sets and concat them together. You could do as the other answer suggests and just get "#result-set-1" from the Map, but I would suggest at the very least converting the ResultSet to an application-represented object ("Thing" pojo) before returning from the dao method. I think that concatening the result-sets together is probably a more durable solution, unless someone can think of a reason as to why not.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public List<Thing> read(String testParam) {
    List<SqlParameter> parameters = Arrays.asList(new SqlParameter(Types.NVARCHAR));
    CallableStatementCreator csc = new CallableStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call test (?)}");
            cs.setString(1, testParam);
            return cs;
        }
    };
    Map<String, Object> result = jdbcTemplate.call(csc, parameters);

    return result.values().stream().map(o -> fromResultSet((ResultSet) o)
           .flatMap(List::stream).collect(toList());

}

private List<Thing> fromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
    List<Thing> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      Thing thing = new Thing(resultSet.getString("resultCol1"), resultSet.getString("resultCol2")
      list.add(user);
    }
}
```

I modified some code from [Resultset To List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966836/resultset-to-list) to actually parse the result set.