# How to create a List from data in a SQL database using java?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am struggling to find an anwser to this question : how do I create a List with data from a SQL database in Java ? (I am using Android Studio)

I need to create :

- lists for dropdown menus and autoCompleteTextView. For these, I need all the values of a specific column, not the whole line ("what are the different brands that exist in my table ?")
- lists for all objects sharing the same attribute ("which objects have the same brand ?")

Here is my constructor for the database :

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "favori TEXT, " +
                "type TEXT, " +
                "marque TEXT, " +
                "nom TEXT, " +
                "nomGenerique TEXT, " +
                "image BLOB, " +
                "prix TEXT, " +
                "codeBarres TEXT, " +
                "quantite TEXT, " +
                "quantiteRestante TEXT, " +
                "notes TEXT)");

    }
```

And this is my data model (in a Modele.class) - I have all the getters and setters after this - :

```
public InventaireAlcool(int id, Boolean favori, String type, String marque,
                            String nom, String nomGenerique, byte[] image, int prix,
                            int codeBarres, int quantite, int quantiteRestante, String notes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.favori = favori;
        this.type = type;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.nomGenerique = nomGenerique;
        this.image = image;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.codeBarres = codeBarres;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.quantiteRestante = quantiteRestante;
        this.notes = notes;
    }
```

I have an activity (AjoutReference) where I fill a form and when I click on the save button, this is what it does :

```
Boolean get_favori = favori.isChecked();
                    String get_type = autoCompleteType.getText().toString();
                    String get_marque = autoCompleteMarque.getText().toString();
                    String get_nom = editTextNom.getText().toString();
                    String get_nomGenerique = editTextNomGenerique.getText().toString();
                    String get_prix = editTextPrix.getText().toString();
                    String get_code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
                    String get_quantite = quantite.getText().toString();
                    String get_quantiteRestante = String.valueOf(sliderQuantite.getValue());
                    String get_notes = editTextNotes.getText().toString();
                    boolean res = inventaireDb.ajoutInventaire(get_favori, get_type, get_marque,
                            get_nom, get_nomGenerique, ImageToByte(imageView), get_prix, get_code, get_quantite, get_quantiteRestante, get_notes);
                    if (res == true){
                        Toast.makeText(AjoutReference.this, "Reference added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AjoutReference.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(AjoutReference.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

The data from the database is then displayed on a RecyclerView with this code (in a RecyclerViewAdapter class):

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nomGenerique.setText(inventaireAlcoolList.get(position).getNomGenerique());
        holder.marque.setText(inventaireAlcoolList.get(position).getMarque());
        holder.type.setText(inventaireAlcoolList.get(position).getType());
        Glide.with(this.context).load(inventaireAlcoolList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);
        holder.quantite.setText(String.valueOf(inventaireAlcoolList.get(position).getQuantite()));
```

I could not find any specific documentation or answer clear enough to help :-(

Any advice would be very much welcome!

And if you wonder what I will use this app for : it is to handle my alcohol stock. I currently have an excel table with more than 120 lines and it is a pain to maintain and keep updated (and, no, I'm not a bartender, just a whisky, gin and rhum enthusiast).
The app should allow me to know how many bottles I have, in which condition ("remaining quantity" is a slider that lets me specify how much is left in a bottle and, when I'm out shopping, I can make sure I buy a refill :-)  ), the lowest price I got, to create a "favorites" list...

Edit :
I found the solution thanks to the link provided by Int'l Man of Coding Mystery.
I created methods inside my database class to provide me with lists of column contents. Here is the code, hoping it might help someone else.

```
    public ArrayList getTypeExtract(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT type FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String typeExtract = cursor.getString(0);

            arrayList.add(typeExtract);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

I also learned that :

- `"SELECT type FROM "` returns the `type` column from the database. I can add other columns just by adding their name : `"SELECT type, marque FROM "` for instance.
- `cursor.getString(0)` the `0` is the column index for the extraction. I have only one column in my example so it has to be `0` (and not column 2, the column index inside the database)...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You didn't attach any code that reads from your database at all. Does that exist anywhere?

Comment: when the programmers are programmers :-)

Comment: do you need read data from database?

Comment: Creating a database table does not populate it with data. You usually add rows to a database table by executing one (or more) INSERT statements. You usually retrieve data from a database table by executing a query, i.e. SELECT statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966870/7619578